# Swift : How to instantiate a new view controller with separate delegate

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, viewcontroller

so i have a question regarding instantiating a new vc when i click on a tableviewcell. Since i have separated my delegate and datasource into separate classes i no longer inherit from ViewController. What are my alternatives to creating a new VC from my delegate class? The other potential problem is that my show array is created in my other separate myDataSource class. How would i pass that to MyDelegate class?

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
        let aDataSource = MyDataSource()
        let aDelegate = MyDelegate()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableView.dataSource = aDataSource
            tableView.delegate = aDelegate
      }
    }


class MyDelegate: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // i want to do the following but it doesn't work since i'm not inheriting from viewcontroller i guess. 

          guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailedShowViewController") as? DetailedShowViewController else {
                fatalError("Unable to instantiate view controller.")
            }

            let item = shows[indexPath.row]
            vc.show = item

            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a delegate and let your view controller inherit this delegate to handle the callback:

```swift
protocol MyViewControllerDelegate {
    func didSelectItemAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

Create a new property such as `weak var myVCDelegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?` in your `MyDelegate` class.

Let your view controller inherit it and assign itself to the delegate from `MyDelegate` (or inject it into the class)

```swift
// In ViewController

aDelegate.myVCDelegate = self


// In MyDelegate class

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // Do some stuff

   // Pass the position of the item.
   myVCDelegate?.didSelectItemAt(indexPath)
}
```

So, when you select a cell, just call the function to pass the indexPath to the view controller then you will be able to get the item by the indexPath from your data source.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding. I can already access my indexPath directly. I'm not having trouble obtaining indexPath but to instantiate a new VC and sharing the properties in datasource.

Comment: Then you can pass your indexPath through the delegate to your VC and get the item from your datasource by this indexPath, then instantiate a new VC in your VC.